# Запрос many-to-many в Entity FrameworkCore

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core

Хронимка которая достаёт Employee по Id task'a, какой аналаг у ef??

```
    ALTER procedure [dbo].[spGetAllEmployeesByTaskId]   
(      
   @TaskId int      
)      
as       
begin      
   Select Employee.Name, Employee.Surname, Employee.SecondName, Employee.Id, Employee.Position, Employee.FilePath
   from Employee
   where Employee.Id IN 
    (Select EmployeeTasks.EmployeeId
        from EmployeeTasks
        where EmployeeTasks.TaskId = @TaskId)
End
```

Comment: var empl = db.Employee.Where(x => x.Id == x.EmployeeTasks.EmployeeId &&  x.EmployeeTasks.TaskId == taskId).ToList(); что-то типа такого, проверяйте

Comment: к сожалению нет, нельзя писать EmployeeTasks.EmployeeId это ведь коллекция

Comment: var empl = db.Employee.Where(x => x.EmployeeTasks.Any(a => x.Id == a.EmployeeId  && a.TaskId == taskId).ToList(); Забыл вставить Any()

Comment: Работает спасибо большое

Comment: пометьте ответ как правильный, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int taskId = 111; //подставьте свой код
var empl = db.Employee.Where(x => x.EmployeeTasks.Any(a => x.Id == a.EmployeeId && a.TaskId == taskId).ToList();
```

как-то так